# В чём разница между ring0 и ring1?

Tags: ос, x86

На собеседовании спросили разницу, я не смог ответить.

В чём разница между ring0 и ring1? Зачем они нужны?

Ещё посоветовали узнать про два и три, но сказали, что это сложно.
Я пробовал гуглить, но там на английском и непонятно.

Может кто-нибудь объяснить понятно?

Answer (score 9):

Это уровни привилегированности процесса. Обычно физически определяется несколькими битами в одном из управляющих регистров CPU.

На уровне (кольце, ринге) 0 могут исполняться любые команды процессора (CPU) с любыми регистрами, на других только их подмножество.

Comment: А зачем они нужны, ринги эти.
Пусть каждый процесс все команды запускает

Comment: @oleg-the-best, если очень просто, то ядро ОС (и начальный загрузчик) работает в ринг 0, а все остальное обычно в ринг 1 (или 3).

Но тут на практике возможны разные варианты, особенно в среде виртуальных машин.

Все это нужно с целью разграничить доступ к ресурсам в многопользовательских системах, обеспечить безопасность и изоляцию процессов друг от друга.

Answer (score 6):

ну.. если вкратце и своими словами - Ring0 или иначе Kernel Mode - самый высокий уровень привилегий, доступный в ОС, позволяет обращаться к защищенным ресурсам - любым данным любой программы в памяти, выполнять операции ввода-вывода через любые порты. Обычно, такими привилегиями никто, кроме ядра ОС, не обладает.
Ring3 или User Mode - Win API